# How do I make a fetch request using NSManagedObject's new fetchRequest function?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, swift3, xcode8-beta2

In iOS 10 the CoreData team added a new "fetchRequest" method to NSManagedObject. It looks like this:

```
public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
```

Which, from what I understand, allows us to replace this:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>(entityName: "MyEntity")
```

with this:

```
let request = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
```

However, when I try to make a simple request like this:

```
let request = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
do {
    results = try request.execute()
} catch let error {
    print("failed to fetch coffee object: \(error)")
}
```

I receive the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={message=Cannot fetch without an NSManagedObjectContext in
>   scope}

So, clearly the error is stating that I need to bring an NSManagedObjectContext into scope. I've been looking for examples but can seem to find a full example of how to perform a request using the new API features.

### Question

Using the latest Core Data API features, how do I make a simple fetch request? The underlying question is how do I bring my NSmanagedObjectCotnext into scope.

I should note that I am able to successfully make a request using the traditional syntax.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok, I figured out two ways of doing this. The **first approach**, which is similar to my example code is just simply:

```
var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!
let request = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
var results : [MyEntity]

 do {
     results = try moc.fetch(request)
 } catch { // error stuff}
```

The **second approach**, which was shown in WWDC 2016 uses a function named "execute" on our fetch request object.

If you view the details on NSFetchRequest you'll see a comment that clearly states that the operation must be performed with in a block.

```
   // Executes the fetch request using the current managed object context. This method must be called from within a block submitted to a managed object context.
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    public func execute() throws -> [ResultType]
```

It's dawned on me that this was the way to perform the fetch:

```
var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!
let request = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
var results : [MyEntity]

moc.perform {
    self.results = try! request.execute()
}
```

**For those who roll their own**

If you are rolling your own code you may find that your code does not compile. Included in the auto-generated code is a new method called fetchRequest that the compiler uses to pass the type along. Here's what the code looks like.

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MyEntity> {
    return NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>(entityName: "MyEntity");
}
```

Comment: With the new generic declarations in Core Data, the `as!` downcasting you're doing is no longer necessary-- the results of the fetch should already have a type of `[MyEntity]`.

Comment: Hey tom, I must be doing something wrong, because the compiler is forcing me to downcast. I'll share an image.

Comment: Not sure. [This is what I did](https://gist.github.com/atomicbird/efbcb04eef24f074ad32dc6f9318965f) and the result is an array of type `[Event]?`, where I can look up attributes by name.

Comment: Hey @TomHarrington I figured it out, I deleted the *nonobjc class func fetchRequest()* from my generated code. Once I added it back in the errors went away. Thank you kindly for point this out...

Comment: Well spotted. It's interesting that the code worked without that.

Comment: Doesn't work, says it wants cast from [NSFetchRequestResult] to [MyEntity]

Comment: @DanBeaulieu figure out what? Your answer is incorrect and does not compile. I don't use codegen for CoreData either.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu thanks Dan, that works! I defined my fetchRequest as `+ (NSFetchRequest<MLCloudFileModel *> *)fetchRequest;` and returned result from `[super fetchRequest]`. That was translated properly to Swift and I was able to call fetchRequest() and receive the right entity back.

Answer (score 10):

For i**OS 10** (**Swift 3**) Following way helped me:

```
var userRecordsArray: [UserProfile] = []

func getData() {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UserProfile")
    let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        userRecordsArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [UserProfile]
    } catch {
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }
}
```