# CoreData difference between context.fetch and fetchRequest.execute

Tags: swift, core-data

I am targeting iOS 10 and can't decide which method should I choose and why? Since both of the below code returns me array of objects.

```
    CoreDataStack.shared.viewContext.perform {
        do {
            let allObjects = try CoreDataStack.shared.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print(allObjects)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    CoreDataStack.shared.viewContext.perform {
        do {
            let allRules = try fetchRequest.execute()
            print(allRules)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: See (duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387125/how-do-i-make-a-fetch-request-using-nsmanagedobjects-new-fetchrequest-function.

Comment: I saw but as I said, this post also says there are two ways of doing it. I have nor problem getting the objects as my code shows. I wonder the difference or drawbacks if any.

Comment: As I understand it from the other answer, the only difference is that `fetchRequest.execute()` *must* be called inside a `perform` block.

Comment: Since I am calling both of them inside the block, are they basically the same? I guess using second one is better since it's syntax looks cleaner.

Comment: @MartinR _Both_ methods must always be called on the proper managed object context. The docs for `NSFetchResult execute` are just  incomprehensible - while the docs for `NSManagedObjectContext fetch` are pretty clear.